# gatsby purge css plugin not installing

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-plugin, css-purge, purgecss

To merge the css in my gatsby project I was trying to install a plugin called purge css but while installing it gives the error and stops
`evo02@evo02:/var/www/html/Evolvan (staging fresh without edits)/evolvan.com-gatsby$ npm install gatsby-plugin-purgecss
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-server-dom-webpack@0.0.0-experimental-c8b778b7f-20220825
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peerOptional react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @apollo/client@3.7.14
npm WARN   node_modules/@apollo/client
npm WARN     peer @apollo/client@"^3" from @graphql-tools/links@8.3.36
npm WARN     node_modules/@graphql-tools/links
npm WARN     2 more (apollo-upload-client, gatsby-source-graphql)
npm WARN   20 more (@gatsbyjs/reach-router, formik, gatsby, gatsby-link, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"0.0.0-experimental-c8b778b7f-20220825" from react-server-dom-webpack@0.0.0-experimental-c8b778b7f-20220825
npm WARN node_modules/react-server-dom-webpack
npm WARN   react-server-dom-webpack@"0.0.0-experimental-c8b778b7f-20220825" from gatsby@5.10.0
npm WARN   node_modules/gatsby
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@0.0.0-experimental-c8b778b7f-20220825
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"0.0.0-experimental-c8b778b7f-20220825" from react-server-dom-webpack@0.0.0-experimental-c8b778b7f-20220825
npm WARN   node_modules/react-server-dom-webpack
npm WARN     react-server-dom-webpack@"0.0.0-experimental-c8b778b7f-20220825" from gatsby@5.10.0
npm WARN     node_modules/gatsby
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: webpack-filter-warnings-plugin@1.2.1
npm ERR! Found: webpack@5.83.1
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   peer webpack@">=4.43.0 <6.0.0" from @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@0.5.10
npm ERR!   node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!     @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@"^0.5.10" from gatsby@5.10.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/gatsby
npm ERR!       peer gatsby@"^5.0.0-next" from babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries@5.10.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries
npm ERR!         babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries@"^5.10.0" from gatsby@5.10.0
npm ERR!         2 more (gatsby-plugin-image, gatsby-plugin-typescript)
npm ERR!       15 more (gatsby-plugin-eslint, gatsby-plugin-google-gtag, ...)
npm ERR!   peer webpack@">=2" from babel-loader@8.3.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/babel-loader
npm ERR!     babel-loader@"^8.3.0" from gatsby@5.10.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/gatsby
npm ERR!       peer gatsby@"^5.0.0-next" from babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries@5.10.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries
npm ERR!         babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries@"^5.10.0" from gatsby@5.10.0
npm ERR!         2 more (gatsby-plugin-image, gatsby-plugin-typescript)
npm ERR!       15 more (gatsby-plugin-eslint, gatsby-plugin-google-gtag, ...)
npm ERR!   18 more (css-loader, css-minimizer-webpack-plugin, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0" from webpack-filter-warnings-plugin@1.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack-filter-warnings-plugin
npm ERR!   webpack-filter-warnings-plugin@"^1.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@4.46.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   peer webpack@"^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0" from webpack-filter-warnings-plugin@1.2.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/webpack-filter-warnings-plugin
npm ERR!     webpack-filter-warnings-plugin@"^1.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /home/evo02/.npm/_logs/2023-07-11T04_50_23_178Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/evo02/.npm/_logs/2023-07-11T04_50_23_178Z-debug-0.log`

treid clearing cache `npm cache clean --force` but it also gives `npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.` now not sure whether it has cleared cache or not

Comment: please reformat the text as it seems to be missing any CR (new lines).  The issue is likely that you need to delimit the code output using ticks ( ```) at the beginning and the end

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/37242) (and possible resolutions) in the Gatsby GitHub project.  It has to do with Gatsby using an experimental version of `react-server-dom-webpack`